# In a room with 20 people, how likely is it there are 4 months with exactly 2 birthdays and 4 others with exactly 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The way I saw it, we could imagine the people are indistinguishable balls that are to be put into $12$ buckets according to their birthdays. The total number of ways to distribute the birthdays is the number of vectors $(x_1,...,x_{12})$ such that $x_1+\cdots x_{12}=20$ which is given by $\binom {31}{11}$. Now choose $4$ months to have $2$ birthdays each, $\binom {12}{4}$, and choose the other $4$ to have $3$ birthdays, $\binom {8}{4}$. Since for each such choice of eight months there is only one way to form a vector whose entries add to $20$, the answer should be
$$\frac {\binom{12}{4} \binom {8}{4}}{\binom{31}{11}}$$
But this answer is wrong by a factor of about 4 and I do not know where the error is coming from. I know that another solution can be obtained by considering the people distinguishable, and I understand that answer just fine, I want to know why my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Can we assume that each month is equally likely, or do we have to account for the months' unequal lengths? And what do we do about February 29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't treat people as indistinguishable. Any arrangement that treats people as *distinguishable* has probability $1/12^{20}$. But different distinguishable arrangements create the same indistinguishable arrangement. For example, the chance that all 20 people were born in January is $1/12^{20}$ (exactly one distinguishable arrangement); the chance that 19 were born in January and 1 was born in February, though, is $20/12^{20}$ (20 distinguishable arrangements, one for each person who could have been the one born in February). But treating people as indistinguishable will give these arrangements equal weight. Since the question is asking the probability of a relatively even distribution of birthdays (i.e., lots of distinguishable arrangements per indistinguishable), your method will give an underestimate.

I think the correct answer is this: $$\frac{20! 12!}{(4!)^3 (3!)^4 (2!)^4 12^{20}}$$
derived as follows: Line up people in any one of $20!$ different ways, and write down one of $12!/4!$ possible lists of eight months. The first $12$ people in line get grouped into threes and each group given to a month; the next $8$ are paired off and each pair given to a month. Then divide out by $(3!)^4 (2!)^4$ because the order of people within each group doesn't matter, then again by $(4!)^2$ because the order of the triads and pairs themselves doesn't matter. This gives the total number of ways to assign months satisfying the hypothesis; divide again by $12^{20}$ to get the final answer $1.0604 \times 10^{-3}$, is a bit more than twice yours.

Answer (score 0):

I find it simpler to conceptualize it as

- choose  $4$ month blocks which will "host" the groups of $2$,  the groups of $3$, and  none.
- distribute the 20 individuals to the $8$ "occupied" months
- divide by unrestricted possibilities

Thus $\dfrac{\dbinom{12}{4,4,4}\dbinom{20}{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}}{12^{20}} \approx1.0604\times 10^{-3}$